# bind to service vs Intent base communication

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I have found that it is possible to communicate with services by use of either Intents or direct binding . Why should direct binding could be useful ? and isn't it a bad practice that sounds like high coupling with components ?

Answer (score 3):

Usually a service which is started with context.StartService() with intents performs a single operation and does not return a result to the caller.and this service can run indefinitely and the service should stop itself by calling stopSelf().

Where as bounded service offers a client server interface that allows components to interact with the service and send requests,get results and even do so across processes with inter process communication(IPC).One or more component can bound to this service.this service run only till at least a component is binded to it else it is destroyed(stopd).

want to know more on bounded and unbounded services. Please refer the below link

[Bounded and unbounded services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Comment: Service can broadcast an Intent with results ,rather than binding if need to communicate ?

Comment: You always have some tricks to communicate. However, the question you have to ask yourself is when you want your service to be running. Do you want it to run only when a client is sending requests and wants answers? (-> bound service) Do you want it to execute a task and send a result? (-> `IntentService`) Do you want it to run independently/permanently and communicate from time to time? (-> started service + bound or started + intents)

Comment: @Joffrey very well said Joffrey!!